# Using JPA to model an existing table that uses a unique key and a sequence number

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I need to access a fairly simple (legacy) table with JPA. The table contains information about configurable (application) menus. The primary key is the menu name (char 10). There is another column called sequence number (int). Together they must be unique. When the table is read it only needs to be read by menu name, and the returned records must be in sequence number order.

```
Name       Seq  Description ...
---------- ---  --------------------
MAINMENU     0  Create an order
MAINMENU     1  Update an order
MAINMENU     2  Log off
ADMINMENU    0  Add a new user
ADMINMENU    1  Work with all users
```

I'm wondering how best to express this in JPA. Should I make the primary key out of both fields (embedded?)? But then I don't want to provide the sequence number when reading. On the other hand the menu name and sequence number together must be unique.

Any suggestions most welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Suggestion? Make an attempt, such as have a class that has a field that maps to the PK column, and then define a unique key on the class.

Comment: @BillyFrost Sorry, I'm new to JPA so I was really trying to find out if there was a recommended strategy for this pattern. I think I have it working now, at least for DB reads and I will add my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but your answer is "Spring Data JPA" which is NOT the JPA API that you tagged this as. Important to know what API you are using!

Comment: @BillyFrost: The question is about pure JPA mapping, so  the tags were correct. How it was answered that's another story though

Answer (score 0):

I have now used the @IdClass way of defining a composite key. I then added findByNameOrderBySequence as per:

```
public interface MenuRepository extends JpaRepository<Menu, MenuKey> {
    List<Menu> findByNameOrderBySequence(String name);
}
```

to my repository class. It does indeed retrieve the correct menus, in the correct sequence.

I created MenuKey.java to handle the 2 field key:

```
package com.mycomp.myproj.models;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class MenuKey  implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private int sequence;

    public MenuKey() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSequence() {
        return sequence;
    }

    public void setSequence(int sequence) {
        this.sequence = sequence;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (name+sequence).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof MenuKey)) {
            return false;
        }
        MenuKey mk = (MenuKey) obj;
        return mk.name.equals(name) && mk.sequence == sequence;
    }
}
```

I then created Menu.java to map the table and refer to MenuKey in the @IdClass annotation:

```
package com.mycomp.myproj.models;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@IdClass(MenuKey.class)
@Entity
@Table(name="MENUS")
public class Menu {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "MENU", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SEQN", nullable = false)
    private int sequence;

    @Column(name = "MNTX", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "OPTP", nullable = false)
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "OPVN", nullable = false)
    private String program;

    public String getNAme() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSequence() {
        return sequence;
    }

    // the other getters and setters etc.
}
```

Comment: Your question was about "how to map the mode to JPA Entity". This answer is how to query for data using already mapped model, so basically you did not answer the question you have asked. Would be good if you also added mapping definitions, how did you map your Menu and MenuKey.